# Is it possible to get information about which advice has been caught in an adviceexecution pointcut?

Tags: aspectj

I have an aspect in my application that intercepts every advice execution on the system. I want to be able to identify which advice is being "intercepted" by my adviceexecution pointcut like this

//... some code in AdviceInspector.aj

```
    before(): adviceexecution() && !within(AdviceInspector) {
    System.out.println("advice execution being intercepted");
            // TODO : get a way to know which advice execution has been intercepted
}
```

//... further code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Signature of the advice from the joinPoint. Signature has various methods to describe it. If it is just for debugging the toString() method describes it nicely

```
before(): adviceexecution() && !within(AdviceInspector) {
    org.aspectj.lang.Signature sig = thisJoinPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature();
    //It is also valid to do 
    //Signature sig =  thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
    System.out.println(sig);
}
```